# How to manage relative imports in python?

Tags: python

I have a code with following structure:

```
  mainDir/
         /foo/ __init__.py
         /foo/foo.py  (i am importing bar here)
         /__init__.py
         /bar.py
```

Now, foo.py has an import like

```
from ..bar import *
```

And inside mainDir I am trying to run: `python -m foo.foo`. But I am getting:

> ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package in foo.py for trying to import bar

I am not looking for `sys.path` solutions but rather creating modules? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolute import:

```
from bar import *  # though you shouldn't be using import * anyway
```

Relative imports have to stay within a package. You can't step out of the package heirarchy entirely and import a top-level module with a relative import.